# Read and write to a .txt file in a folder

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and was wondering what is the best way to accomplish the following:

1. Suppose I have a .txt file in a folder in my android app (e.g. folder A somewhere in my app's folder hierarchy) . I would like to read and process each line of this .txt file.
2. I want to write a string into a .txt file and put this file into an existing folder (e.g. folder B). As a side note, where should I put folder B when developing my app?

I understand this is a "beefy" question as it's 2 questions in one. However, I believe anybody who wants to know the answer to one of them will want the answer for the other question as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is not directly supported.  However you can package read only initial data as an asset (which is not quite a literal File) and then at runtime create writable files in the private or external storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do that and it's working fine! Hope it helps you! :)

1.

```
try {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("pathToYourFile");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String lineString;

    while ((lineString = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // the line is stored in lineString
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2.

```
// Gets external storage directory
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

// File's directory
File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "yourFilesDirectory");

// The file
File file = new File(dir, "nameOfTheFile");

// Writes a line to file
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    writer.write("A line\n");
    writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the context of my application, I save these files in a folder inside the external storage directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we back up our database on the device

```
    public static String backupPath = "backup"
    public static String Path = "/mnt/sdcard/<your path>";
    public static String databaseName = "toc_data";
    public static String dbBackupIndex = "0";


public static void backupDB() {
    String toPath = Path + "/" + backupPath + dbName;
    toPath = toPath.substring(0, toPath.lastIndexOf(".")) + dbBackupIndex + ".db";



    File from = new File(Path + dbName);
    File to = new File(toPath);

    try {
        copyFile(from, to);

        int newIndex = Integer.valueOf(dbBackupIndex) + 1;

        if (newIndex >= 10) {
            newIndex = 0;
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);

    boolean throwFNFE = true;

    int errorCount = 1;
    while (errorCount < 4) {
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
            Log.d("Copy File", "Copy File OS out: " + out.toString());

            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();

            throwFNFE = false;
            break;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                errorCount++;
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    if (throwFNFE) {
        FileNotFoundException fnfe = new FileNotFoundException("Could not find SD card after 3 attempts");
        throw fnfe;
    }
}
```